# Java,Spring,Push Notification

Tags: java, spring, notifications, push

I want to implement push notification in java so please help me out

1-Each time a new record(Message) pushed into data base(due to event created by some other user),  a push notification should be sent to specific Logged in user automatically.

2-Content of the push notification should be the message present in the db.

3-If there are multiple messages, then the user should receive them one by one in a queue fashion.

4-Most important thing is the logged in user need not have to trigger any event to get notification, user should receive it automatically throughout the session.

Comment: This is BROAD. I mean this involves both back-end and front-end (which framework), it's not something that can be contained in an answer.

Comment: Take a look at websocket, Spring has a good support.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Server Sent Events. Java provides SseEmitter to send timely notifications.
You can use EventSource API in JavaScript to trigger the SSE event stream and in the server-side, loop the database query code which is wrapped by an ExecutorService - which can spin of separate thread based on the initialization.
Put SSE timeout to -1 for listening for an infinite amount of time.

Please note this answer is only a hint. Use these to explore more from the internet.